# Install on 32Bit Machine

Tags: system-installation, 32-bit

How do I install 18.04 on a 32Bit machine?

The graphical version, not the console version - which I have already installed.

I answered NO to password but when I boot to Ubuntu I'm asked for a username and password - which of course there is none.

I would like to do a re-install but to the graphical Ubuntu as mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: There is no Ubuntu desktop ISO for 32bit Ubuntu 18.04; outside of netboot (non-gui installer), and some of the flavors. You could install a flavor (xubuntu, lubuntu, can't remember if others provided x86 installs sorry), then add the `ubuntu-desktop` to it, or use the netboot install option (which has a x86).   ps: take a look at karel's possible duplicate notice too!  (your machine doesn't meet gnome's required specs)

Comment: Thanks. As it turned out, the Lubuntu flavour worked perfectly on my 32 bit Dell Latitude D510. Although it doesn't like automatic Ubuntu upgrades which, after downloading abort with a message about 64 bit upgrades not compatible with 32 bit systems.

Comment: Your automatic upgrade issue sounds like you have a x86_64 (64bit) source in your sources.list* file. If you want help on this you'll have to open a new question.  *I used my dell d610 to test Xubuntu &  Lubuntu 19.04 until they were 'sunsetted' (x86 iso's dropped 20-dec-2018 for lubuntu, a couple of weeks after xubuntu)*

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to be looking at Lubuntu or Xubuntu, possibly others, as they both offer 32 bit versions where Ubuntu does not...

Answer (score 0):

The main Ubuntu flavor [doesn't offer 32-bit builds anymore](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2017-September/004212.html) since September of 2017 when that decision was made. However, Ubuntu is based on the [Debian project](https://www.debian.org/distrib/), which does still produce 32-bit builds.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up installing Lubuntu and it works great.